# Apache Spark reduceByKey to sum decimals

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to map an RDD as such (see output for results) and map reduce by the decimal values and I keep getting error. When I tried using reduceByKey() with word count it worked fine. Are decimal values summed differently?

```
val voltageRDD= myRDD.map(i=> i.split(";"))
   .filter(i=> i(0).split("/")(2)=="2008")
   .map(i=> (i(0).split("/")(2),i(2).toFloat)).take(5)
```

Output:

```
voltageRDD: Array[(String, Float)] = Array((2008,1.62), (2008,1.626), (2008,1.622), (2008,1.612), (2008,1.612))
```

When trying to reduce:

```
val voltageRDD= myRDD.map(i=> i.split(";"))
   .filter(i=> i(0).split("/")(2)=="2008")
   .map(i=> (i(0).split("/")(2),i(2).toFloat)).reduceByKey(_+_).take(5)
```

I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2954.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2954.0 (TID 15696, 10.19.240.54): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "?"
```

Comment: are you sure all your data is in that format? in your code the second snippet will run through the whole dataset (since it will do the `reduceByKey` and then `take`) while the first one will run only for the first few records. If somewhere after the first `5` records (after filtering) your `i(2)` is `?` it will crash in the second snippet but not in the first one since spark is lazy.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk thank you for pointing that out. My data set wasn't clean hence not in the same format!

Comment: in that case I added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data contains columns which are not parseable to a float, then you should either filter them out beforehand or treat them accordingly. Such a treatment could mean that you assign a value of `0.0f`, if you see a non-parseable entry. The following code does exactly this.

```scala
val voltageRDD= myRDD.map(i=> i.split(";"))
  .filter(i => i(0).split("/")(2)=="2008")
  .map(i => (i(0).split("/")(2), Try{ i(2).toFloat }.toOption.getOrElse(0.0f)))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _).take(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Short version: you probably have a line for which `i(2)` equals `?`.

As per my comment your data most probably isn't consistent which won't be a problem in the first snippet because of the `take(5)` and no actions that require spark to perform operations on the whole data set. Spark is lazy and therefore will perform computations only until it gets `5` results from the `map -> filter -> map` chain.

The second snippet on the other hand will perform computations on your whole data set so it can perform the `reduceByKey` and only then it will take 5 results therefore it might catch problems which are too far in your data set for the first snippet.